# Probability: Relationship between Multinomial expansion and Combinations

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

### I have the following problem:

Place $K$: where $35\%$ of students live
Place $N$: where $45\%$ of students live
Place $H$: where $20\%$ of students live

$4$ students are randomly selected
What is the probability that $2$ students are from $K$, $1$ from $N$ and $1$ from $H$

My way of solving:
Multinomial term: $(x^2)yz => (K^2)NH$
Coefficient: $\dbinom42\times\dbinom21\times\dbinom11 = 12$

=> $P(2K,1N,1H) = 12 * (0.35)^2 * (0.45) * (0.2) = 0.1323$

---

So, I thought about how to solve this in another way:

Sample space = $\dbinom{100}4$
$2$ students from $K = \dbinom{35}2$
$1$ student from $N = \dbinom{45}1$
$1$ student from $H = \dbinom{20}1$

$P(2K,1N,1H) = \dfrac{\left[ \dbinom{35}2\dbinom{45}1\dbinom{20}1 \right]}{  \dbinom{100}4} = 0.1366$

I have problems understanding why the second way does not give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't specify that there are a total of 100 students, only specifies percentages.

You will find that if you increase N to 200, say, the figure will change to 0.1344,

and if you increase it to 2000, it will become 0.1325.

(i.e. come nearer and nearer to the correct figure by the first approach)

*Note*

To be a bit more technical, the hypergeometric distribution converges to the binomial (or multinomial) as $N$ tends to infinity. See a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330553/proof-that-the-hypergeometric-distribution-with-large-n-approaches-the-binomia)