# What is the probability of choosing 2 bulbs that are not defective?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a box of 20 bulbs, 2 are defective. What is the probability of choosing 2 bulbs that are not defective ?

---

I solved it by hypergeometric theorem and got it correct.

I want to know that how binomial theorem can solve this ?

Comment: You cannot use the binomial distribution (theorem) because it is without replacement.

Comment: @callculus, plz elaborate ?

Comment: One assumption which has to be made to use the binomial distribution is that you have an experiment without replacement.

Comment: @callculus, Then how the question will be changed inorder to apply BT ?

Comment: Every bulb which has been drawn has to be replaced before the next bulb is drawn. But then it is another setting/exercise.

Comment: Maybe of interest http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330553/proof-that-the-hypergeometric-distribution-with-large-n-approaches-the-binomia or http://wiki.stat.ucla.edu/socr/index.php/AP_Statistics_Curriculum_2007_Limits_Bin2HyperG

Answer (score 3):

edit: The binomial theorem relies on the probabilities of success and failure being constant, whereas here they are not. Once you remove the lightbulb, success has a new probability of $17/19$, no longer $18/20$, as it would be with replacement.

What is the probability of the first bulb not being defective? $18/20=9/10$.

And the second? $17/19$. You have removed one of the good lightbulbs, so you must subtract 1 from the original numerator as well as the denominator.

This yields a probability of both being good bulbs
$$
\frac{9}{10}*\frac{17}{19}=\frac{153}{190}
$$

Comment: The question is "I want to know that how **binomial theorem** can solve this "  I don´t see that you answer referring to that.

Comment: It cannot, as you commented. I offered an intuitive way to solve the problem

Comment: I like this kind of intuitive ways, much better than just using the hypergeometric distribution. But it doesn´t answer the question.

Comment: @callculus in that case, the answer is just "you cannot use the binomial theorem to solve this." Would you be satisfied if I added this in at the start?

Comment: @qbert, yes please !! I need the reasoning. Actually I solved it by this method too.

Answer (score 1):

Binomial coefficients come in handy here.

$$\frac {\binom {18}2}{\binom {20}2}=\frac {153}{190}$$