# Hypergeometric distribution convergences binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, binomial-distribution

I don't understand the following statement:
Let $X_N$ , N $=$ 1,2, ... random variables with hypergeometric distribution; Parameter ($N$,[P$N$],n).

Show that:

$$\lim_{N\to \infty} P(  X_N  = k ) =  \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Does this means that the hypergeometric distribution approaches binomial distribution for N $\rightarrow$ $\infty$ ?

Can somebody give me only the beginning of this proof?

Comment: I would suggest to read the first line of this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/330553/349501

Comment: And that is also a possible duplicate

Comment: Oh I didn't found that. I'm sorry. Thank you very much. But I have one more question: In the other post they fixed p=$r/N$. I have [P$N$]. What is the difference?

Comment: do you mean the integer part of $pN$?

Comment: yes. I don't understand why we consider the integer part of pN instead of a fixed p with p=r/N.

Comment: there is no big difference. You could also say set $p=r/N$ fixed and then you would have $[pN]=[r]$ and the calculations would remain (almost) the same.