# Normal approximation to the hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, approximation

> (Feller Volume 1 p.194 Q.10) Normal approximation to the hypergeometric distribution. Let $n, m , k$ be positive integers and suppose that they tend to infinity in such a way that $\frac{r}{n+m} \to t, \frac{n}{n+m} \to p, \frac{m}{n+m} \to q, h(k-rp) \to x$ where $h = 1/\sqrt{(n+m)pqt(1-t)}$. Prove that 
>   $${n \choose k}{m \choose r-k}/{n+m \choose r} \sim h\phi(x).$$
>   Hint: Use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution rather than Stirling's formula.

$\phi(x)$ is a normal pdf and $\sim$ denotes that the ratio converges to 1 for large sample size.

I know that the hypergeometric distribution can be approximated by the binomial distribution (for example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330553/proof-that-the-hypergeometric-distribution-with-large-n-approaches-the-binomia)). Also, by the Demoivre-Laplace theorem, the binomial distribution can be approximated by the normal distribution. However, I am struggling to prove this question using the conditions given. Can you give me some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: One version of the normal approximation to the binomial is: Let $p_n+q_n=1$ with $p_n\to p$ and $q_n\to q$. If $n$ and $k$ tend to infinity in such a way that  $(k-np_n)/\sqrt{np_nq_n}\to y$, then
$$
{n\choose k}p_n^kq_n^{n-k}\sim \frac1{\sqrt{npq}}\phi(y)\tag N
$$
as $n\to\infty$. To apply this to the hypergeometric, the trick is to write
$$
\frac{\displaystyle{n\choose k}{m\choose r-k}}{\displaystyle{n+m\choose r}}=
\frac{\displaystyle{r\choose k}{n+m-r\choose n-k}}{\displaystyle{n+m\choose n}}=
\frac{\displaystyle{r\choose k}p_n^kq_n^{r-k}{n+m-r\choose n-k}p_n^{n-k}q_n^{m+k-r}}{\displaystyle{n+m\choose n}p_n^nq_n^m}
$$
where $p_n:=\frac n{n+m}$, $q_n:=\frac m{n+m}$. Now apply the normal approximation (N) three times to the RHS.